# How do I run the psvm in my jar file from AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a jar file that runs locally if I run `java -jar jarname.jar`. It has one class called `Main` in no package. How can I run this with AWS Lambda? I have a Lambda set up but it asks for a Handler (see image) and I don't know what I put in there if I just want to run my jar. I get the errors below when the lambda runs with the configuration below.

```
2021-03-01T09:01:14.126-05:00   START RequestId: 8f7eea07-3931-4c29-b965-7963fce3b64e Version: $LATEST

2021-03-01T09:01:14.128-05:00   Class not found: Main: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)

2021-03-01T09:01:14.154-05:00   END RequestId: 8f7eea07-3931-4c29-b965-7963fce3b64e

2021-03-01T09:01:14.154-05:00


REPORT RequestId: 8f7eea07-3931-4c29-b965-7963fce3b64e  Duration: 27.60 ms  Billed Duration: 28 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 63 MB  Init Duration: 36.85 ms 
REPORT RequestId: 8f7eea07-3931-4c29-b965-7963fce3b64e Duration: 27.60 ms Billed Duration: 28 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 63 MB Init Duration: 36.85 ms
```

Also, when I tried to upload my jar directly it rejected it so I put it in a zip and it worked.

[image]

Comment: you will need a class and a handler method name too ! so, you pass in `Main::someMethod` to Handler

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a class to your Java application that implements `RequestHandler` as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler.html). That will be then handler class you specify in the runtime settings.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-java.html) is the Documentation for creating a simple Java Lambda.

Handler name will be `ClassWithPackage::methodName`

AWS will simply create an object for the given class and call the given method(should be public) by passing necessary input. we can't use psvm, since it's static. we need a non-static method.

In your case, since there is no package we can give `Main::someMethod` in handler, but method name is must, otherwise, it doesn't know which method to call. We could have multiple methods, each representing different lambda function.

if we have dependencies, it is important create a deployment-package, which embeds all the dependent jars and create a single jar file.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-package.html) is the documentation for creating a single-jar. For maven using maven-shade-plugin.

Comment: I am already using maven-shade-plugin to have everything in my jar at once, it can run anywhere with no external dependencies. When I tried to upload my jar into AWS it tells me that it cant properly unzip the file. should I put the jar inside a zip?

Comment: No. jar generated by maven-shade-plugin should work. its already kind of zipped into .jar, we don't need to zip it again. can you add your pom.xml to the question? Also the error in the question, means you are able to upload and run the lambda, correct?

Comment: At this moment when I uploaded a jar with the fixes you provided I am not getting class not found exceptions yet my code is not doing what it is supposed to... When I run it from command line on my PC it says "No main manifest" because maven isn't building one...

Comment: Ok. cool. any errors when you run the lambda in console or cloudwatch?

Comment: No errors in console, but it does say things like START and REPORT which I assume means its running

Comment: Yes. I think, everything seems good. Try to add some sysout statements, it should print them. also with maven-share-plugin, it generates two jars , you probably have upload right one but just saying that we need the jar that doesn't start with original-*

Comment: https://gist.github.com/YHDiamond/8fc8358259801280a566867c1820968d my code is here and in AWS I put `Main::method`. I am also not using the `original` jar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229349/discussion-between-balu-vyamajala-and-yhdiamond).